# I want to build google assistant on my android application

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, grpc-java, google-assist-api

i want to build ai speaker to use google assistant on android app not android things.
may be i think i will use grcp because python not execute on android app.
Is there any way I can use Google Assistant already installed in my mobile phone ?
my cellphone already has a google assistant !!

Comment: Do you mean text to speech or voice controll?

Comment: @MilosLulic no.. I just want to bring whole functions in GoogleAssistant

Answer (score 0):

Commit b790b0b puts everything into a single class, making it easier to integrate into other Android devices.

Kindly check the below link.

https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant/commit/b790b0be91b5a743fb847af6a6c95f19459162de